# jQuery selected link text color not changing permanently

Tags: jquery

I have a list of links for navigating from one page to another. The selected link changes color briefly (to red), and then goes back to the default color. I've read quite a few messages about this problem, but none of my solutions are working.

php file:

```
<div class="navBar">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>     <a href="about.php">About</a>     <a href="galleries.php">Gallery</a>     <a href="equipment.php">Equipment</a>     <a href="links.php">Links</a>     <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </div>

   <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                alert('in navBar');
                /*$('.aNavBar').click(function(event)
                    {

                    };*/

                $('.navBar a').click(function ()
                    {
                        alert("in click function");
                        $('.navBar a.selected').removeClass('selected');
                        $(this).addClass('selected');
                        $('.navBar a.lastclicked').removeClass('lastclicked');
                        $(this).addClass('lastclicked');
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

css file:

```
.navBar
{
    background: white;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 10%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre;
    width: 100%;
}

.navBar.selected
{
    color: red;
}

.navBar a.lastclicked
{
    color: red;
}

.navBar a.selected
{
    color: red;
}
```

As you can see, I've attempted to use 'selected' and 'lastclicked'.

Comment: your code does not make sense, you are removing the selected and lastclicked class and again you are adding same class. Do you want to add selected and lastclicked class to the parent div having navbar class??

Comment: When the link is clicked, the browser navigates to a new page, the elements are not the same that received the red classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add/remove class won't matter since it's lost when the user navigates from page to page.

An option would be to determine the page being viewed from the URL with a regular expression like:

```
var href = 'http://www.example.com/test/pagename/';
//href = location.href;
var page = href.match(/^.*?\/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1];
// This will give you 'pagename'

href = 'http://www.example.com/test/index.php';
page = href.match(/^.*?\/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1];
// This will give you index.php
```

From there you can do something like:

```
 $.each($('.navBar a'), function(i,e){
    if($(e).attr('href') === page){
        $(e).addClass('selected');
    }
  })
```

To determine if the page being viewed matches any of the hrefs, if so, add the selected class.

This is not without shortcomings though:

- If file extensions are being removed by `htaccess` for example, the URL will say `index` while the href would say `index.php`, therefor no match.
- If the URL is something like `http://www.example.com/` this will return `www.example.com`

There needs to be additional work done to address things like this.

Hope it helps though!

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhuteLat/2/) showing the concept in action.